# Maintaining TLB entries across processes

Tags: tlb

The Translation Lookaside Buffer is a resource used by all cores in a system for efficient virtual to physical address translation. In a multi-core/multi-processor architecture, there is a probability that a TLB lookup with be required for the same virtual page address (in different processes) that maps to two different physical page frames simultaneously. How is this conflict handled in the TLB ?

Ulrich Drepper's article http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf does talk about extended TLB tagging (which is still limited by number of bits used for the tag). How do the more recent CPUs handle this issue ? Any references or links to relevant articles would be very helpful.